# The speed of an unconstant motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image]

There's already the solution for the problem but I still don't understand why the velocity can't be calculated by just 
$$ a = (v(t))'= -B_0 + B_1t \Rightarrow v(t) = -B_0t + 1/2B_1t^2$$

Also, both my solution and given solution tell that at t=0, the velocity will be 0. It is the point that I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not carry out your integration quite correctly. We have:

$$ a(t)= -B_0+B_1t $$
$$ v(t) = \int\! a(t)dt=-B_0 t+\frac{1}{2}B_1t^2+C$$
Then plugging in conditions to solve for $C$ we get:

$$ v(t_s)=0 $$
$$ 0=-B_0t_s+\frac{1}{2}B_1t_s^2+C $$
$$ C=B_0t_s-\frac{1}{2}B_1t_s^2  $$

Now we can plug in $t=0$ and solve for $v(0)$

$$ v(0)=-B_0(0)_s+\frac{1}{2}B_1(0)+B_0t_s-\frac{1}{2}B_1t_s^2 $$

So we see that indeed:

$$v(0)=B_0t_s-\frac{1}{2}B_1t_s^2$$

In general, when solving Initial Value problems you need to use a definite integral or solve for your integration constants with the initial values.

Comment: Well, that drives me to another problem. How about if $t_s$ is given at the point the velocity is nonzero. That will make C different and then $v(0)$ will change too but in fact $v(0)$ is still unchange.

Comment: It will not actually make the answer change.  You have to remember that different velocities exist at different times all the way throughout the plane's motion.  A proper change in time and velocity will still yield the same velocity at time 0.  This is guaranteed to us through the existence and uniqueness theorems from differential equations.  There will only be one solution to the motion, and will yield identical values for whatever initial conditions are given as long as they correspond to the motion of the plane.

Comment: Symbolically, the answer may look different, but the numerical values will end up being the same.

Comment: Thank, now I get the idea. Would you mind do me a favor, recommending some books about calculus. I think I needs to learn more about this.

Comment: Sure, I used "Early Transcendentals" by Taylor. The book is pretty comprehensive for starting off learning calculus.  There are many other good books out there though. The Dover books on introductory calculus are pretty good in both price and content too.